# separate modules.exports functions cannot call each other

Tags: node.js, require, node-modules

I've created two modules.export functions, and in some cases they need each other.

Ex:

```
// a.js
modules.exports = function(){ b(); }

// b.js
modules.exports = function(){ console.log('b'); }

// main.js
let a = require('a.js');
let b = require('b.js');

a();
```

As above, it will throw an error saying that 'b()' doesn't exist. In regular JS, you can define functions that call other functions no problem so long as the definition is in a equal or higher scope, so I'm not sure why that behaviour is not happening with modules.exports.

I really don't want to have to require b() in a.js as that would create a lot of overhead in my project.

*EDIT*

Unfortunately adding the modules to the global scope is not an option.

Comment: You _could_ use `global`, but requiring it manually is recommended anyway. The overhead is a tradeoff for making your files' dependencies on other files explicit. In "regular JS" (I'm guessing you mean browser JS), relying on globals can lead to issues with ambiguity (as in, where the hell did this function come from?) and possibly name collisions.

Comment: you are missing `const b = require('./b.js')` inside of `a.js`

Answer (score 0):

this is your answer friend :

```
//a.js
const b = require('./b.js')
modules.exports = function(){ b(); }

//b.js
modules.exports = function(){ console.log('b'); }


// main.js
let a = require('a.js');
let b = require('b.js');

a();
```